# Why does the callback hell works and the async/await doesnt? (in this particular case that i am testing)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, callback

I have this two codes (one i use callback hell and other async/await):

```js
function sleep(seconds) {
  const date = Date.now();
  milliseconds = seconds * 1000;
  let currentDate = null;
  do {
    currentDate = Date.now();
  } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}

const callBackHell = () => {
  return Promise.resolve().then((v) => {
    sleep(1);
    console.log("ameno");
    return Promise.resolve().then((v) => {
      sleep(1);
      console.log("dorime");
      return Promise.resolve().then((v) => {
        sleep(1);
        return console.log("latireno");
      });
    });
  });
};

console.log(1);

callBackHell();

console.log(2);

console.log(3);
```

The callback hell works as i imagined (the string logs appear lastly).

Then i tried to convert the same code but with async/await, like this:

```js
function sleep(seconds) {
  const date = Date.now();
  milliseconds = seconds * 1000;
  let currentDate = null;
  do {
    currentDate = Date.now();
  } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}

const consoleMusical = async (letra) => {
  sleep(1);
  console.log(letra);
};

async function codeBlockerAwait() {
  await consoleMusical("ameno");
  await consoleMusical("dorime");
  await consoleMusical("latiereno");
}

console.log(1);
codeBlockerAwait();
console.log(2);
console.log(3);
```

Now the first await blocks the main thread while the other two keeps showing lastly. What am i doing wrong?

Edit with @Muhammad Saquib Shaikh solution:

```js
function sleep(seconds) {
  const date = Date.now();
  milliseconds = seconds * 1000;
  let currentDate = null;
  do {
    currentDate = Date.now();
  } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}

const consoleMusical = async (letra) => {
  sleep(1);
  console.log(letra);
};

async function codeBlockerAwait() {
  await consoleMusical("ameno");
  await consoleMusical("dorime");
  await consoleMusical("latiereno");
}

(async function () {
  console.log(1);
  await codeBlockerAwait();
  console.log(2);
  console.log(3);
})();
```

It is not the same output as the first one.

Comment: Nature of ```codeBlockerAwait();``` function is asynchronus you need to place await before the function call .

Comment: @Muhammad Saquib Shaikh, No, that would produce `1 ameno dorime latiereno 2 3`, not `1 2 3 ameno dorime latiereno` like the first snippet.

Comment: @MuhammadSaquibShaikh, if you use that code it will produce 1 ameno dorime latiereno 2 3, not 1 2 3 ameno dorime latiereno like the first snippet. Just like ikegami said!

Comment: @Muhammad Saquib Shaikh, Extra parens aside, that does not produce the correct output. It produces `1
ameno
dorime
latiereno
2
3` instead of `1 2 3 ameno dorime latiereno`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now the first await blocks the main thread while the other two keeps showing lastly. What am i doing wrong?

The reason that `ameno` gets logged up front is that you have that log statement *before* any `await`s. To evaluate the line `await consoleMusical("ameno");` it has to execute `consoleMusical('ameno')`, get its return value, and only then can it `await`.

The other console.logs happen after the await, so they will get queued up as microtasks to run after the rest of the currently-executing code.

In contrast, all of the console.logs of callBackHell are inside the first promise. So all of them will be queued up as microtasks.

---

This problem will go away if you use an asynchronous sleep rather than a synchronous one. And as a bonus, you don't lock up the browser:

```js
function sleep(seconds) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000);
  });
}

const consoleMusical = async (letra) => {
  await sleep(1);
  console.log(letra);
};

async function codeBlockerAwait() {
  await consoleMusical("ameno");
  await consoleMusical("dorime");
  await consoleMusical("latiereno");
}

console.log(1);
codeBlockerAwait();
console.log(2);
console.log(3);
```

If you absolutely must have a synchronous sleep, while still wanting to keep the same order of operations, you'll need to add an additional await.

```js
function sleep(seconds) {
  const date = Date.now();
  milliseconds = seconds * 1000;
  let currentDate = null;
  do {
    currentDate = Date.now();
  } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}

const consoleMusical = async (letra) => {
  sleep(1);
  console.log(letra);
};

async function codeBlockerAwait() {
  await undefined; // <--------- added
  await consoleMusical("ameno");
  await consoleMusical("dorime");
  await consoleMusical("latiereno");
}


console.log(1);
codeBlockerAwait();
console.log(2);
console.log(3);
```

Comment: ok, but what's the solution? What would you change to have `codeBlockerAwait` return immediately?

Comment: ```((async function(){   console.log(1);   await codeBlockerAwait();   console.log(2);   console.log(3); })();``` change your code with this line of code and it will work

Comment: @ikegami this situation is only arising because their sleep code is a synchronous busy loop. That's not a realistic thing to do in the real world, so the fix is probably to make the sleep code be asyncronous (eg, a setTimeout wrapped in a promise) and leave `codeBlockerAwait` the way it is.

Comment: @Muhammad Saquib Shaikh, Extra parens aside, that does not produce the correct output. It produces `1
ameno
dorime
latiereno
2
3` instead of `1 2 3 ameno dorime latiereno`

Comment: I added a snippet of @MuhammadSaquibShaikh example to better ilustrate my problem!

Answer (score 0):

`.then` code is guaranteed to be executed asynchronously. As such, `callBackHell` returns immediately.

`codeBlockerAwait`, on the other hand, only returns when it yields from executing an `await`. That happens after `consoleMusical("ameno")` has finished executing.

If you had a more realistic example, things would be much more similar. For example, if we replace the blocking `sleep` function with an asynchronous one, you'll get the expected behaviour.

```js
function sleep(seconds) {
  return new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000);
    }
  );
}

const consoleMusical = async (letra) => {
  await sleep(1);
  console.log(letra);
};

async function codeBlockerAwait() {
  await consoleMusical("ameno");
  await consoleMusical("dorime");
  await consoleMusical("latiereno");
}

console.log(1);
codeBlockerAwait();
console.log(2);
console.log(3);
```

Comment: Doh, I got called away, and what my answer provides was added to the other answer while I was away. But you know what, I think this explanation is nice and clean, so I'll leave it up in case it helps someone.